Router SSID disappearing from list of scanned networks on all clients periodically
I have a H68K Linkstar router with an Openwrt snapshot installed. My clients attempt to manually connect when they so choose, but the router SSID does not appear in the list of available networks. Upon refreshing, every 10 or 15 seconds for about four or five seconds, the SSID appears and the client can connect to it. However, if the client waits too long it disappears again. Connecting to it as a hidden network does not work. Any connection, once established, is maintained. The only problem is the painful discovery process. I have tried shortening the beacon interval on the Luci web UI but it should work as it was left default.
More info:
Wifi module: M7921 (Wifi 6)
Openwrt config:
config wifi-device 'radio0'
       option type 'mac80211'
       option path '3c0000000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0'
       option channel '153'
       option band '5g'
       option htmode 'HT40'
       option cell_density '0'
       option country 'US'

config wifi-iface 'default_radio0'
       option device 'radio0'
       option network 'lan'
       option mode 'ap'
       option ssid 'H68K'
       option encryption 'psk'
       option key 'XXX'

This occurs with all clients across Android, Windows, Linux (wpa_supplicant) etc. It occurs both with a static frequency broadcasting and auto frequency switching. It has occured on both a 2022 and 2023 snapshot of Openwrt. I really hope this is a config setting I can change, but I fear it is a firmware bug with the out-of-tree patches to the M7921 wifi module.
Is there any tips on what setting could be causing the router to disappear from scans often? Otherwise perhaps a log that could show what the wifi driver is doing during these times.

Look at the OpenWrt log files. IDK, but maybe /var/log/*?
